# Flag handling popin incomplete

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

When visiting a question that has flags, those show up in a popin at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

I like this feature a lot. However, there is a curious separation: I can dismiss the flag in the popin, but not act on it. For closing or deleting the question, I have to use the buttons in the flag list or the "flagless" links directly beneath the question.

I propose to include all buttons in the popin. That would make for a more consistent experience (with the flag list) and would allow to act on the flag after having read the question and (then) the flag comment without having to go back to the question (which might include scrolling).

Answer (score 3):

I disagree. There's already a lot of clutter. Having the close and delete buttons on the flag dashboard makes the common actions readily available, so the usefulness trumps the clutter. On the question page, they're redundant, and not very intuitive (do the buttons have the same meaning? Why don't I see an additional button to protect or lock?).

One related improvement I'd like to see is to split that button in two:

- dismiss
- dismiss with feedback

(instead of having a button that pops up a two-entry menu).

Comment: If I use the "normal" links underneath questions or answers, I am not prompted for whether the flag was helpful. At the very least, it is not transparent what happens (because the flag is silently marked as helpful), in the worst case the flag is just gone.

Comment: @Raphael That's by design: when you close or delete the flagged post, it is the necessary sole response to the flag in 99% of the cases. I don't recall ever closing or deleting and still wanted to leave the flag undismissed. I might want to leave a comment after closing, or review other answers on the page, etc., but it's enough to leave the page with the flag for that.

Comment: Still, it is inconsistent with the flag list UI and is intransparent. So maybe by design, but good design?